# Consulta 2 tabelas SQL trazer todos os resultados

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Estou fazendo uma consulta SQL para trazer os usuários, mas eu consulto 2 tabelas: users e users_vip

No users tem todos os usuarios e no users_vip só os que são vip (ativos ou não).

Quando faço minha consulta unindo as 2 tabelas ele só traz quem tem cadastro no vip, pq uso o WHERE u.id = uv.iduser, a consulta está assim:

```
SELECT uv.status, u.id, u.name, u.username, u.email, uv.datapedido, uv.dataconfirm, uv.datafinal
FROM euk_users u, euk_users_vip uv
WHERE u.id = uv.iduser
```

Se eu tiver 10 usuarios comuns e 1 VIP, a consulta só vai trazer esse 1 VIP.

Eu queria que ao consultar ele também trouxesse os usuarios que estão no users mas não estão no users_vip, com os dados ausentes em branco, em zero, ou alguma coisa assim. Como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você consegue fazer isso usando o [`LEFT JOIN`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp), que vai te retornar tudo que tem na tabela da direita e o que tiver na tabela da esquerda por exemplo:

```
SELECT 
    uv.status, 
    u.id, u.name, 
    u.username, 
    u.email, 
    uv.datapedido, 
    uv.dataconfirm, 
    uv.datafinal
FROM euk_users u
LEFT JOIN euk_users_vip uv
ON u.id = uv.iduser;
```

Comment: Show! Exatamente isso, obrigado!